# How to make if~elseif statement using by Java stream and lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to make grade program like below.

But I must do not use if~else statement.

Must use Java Stream and lambda function.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("score : ");
   int score = sc.nextInt();

   switch(score/10) {
        case 10:
        case 9:
            System.out.println("A");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("B");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("C");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("D");
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("F");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I don't know how you'd use streams here, really.

Comment: You current solution does not use `if`-`else`.

Comment: *How to make if~elseif statement using by Java stream and lambda function?* - `if-else` and streams/lambdas have nothing in common. If you're solving some task/homework, which asks you to use streams, maybe you can provide a context what they ask exactly for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream is more of a looping construct than a conditional construct. And since the outcomes of one stage can be chained to another, they need to maintain uniformity in the object structure to be passed from one to the other.
So, I don't think there is a way to write if-else statements as separate stages.
However, you can wrap them inside a map and do the conditional work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Arrays.stream(args)
   .map(Integer::parseInt)
   .forEach(score => {
      switch(score/10) {
        case 10:
        case 9:
            System.out.println("A");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("B");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("C");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("D");
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("F");
        }
   })
}
```

Comment: `=>` should probably be `->`. Also you could use `mapToInt` for potentially better performance. Maybe it would also be good to add some comments, especially to the `map` call since OP might not know about method references.

Comment: Changing the OP’s program from reading from `System.in` to streaming over the `args` argument is not even remotely addressing the task.

Comment: The array can come from anywhere. The question was about conditions on a stream. I guess I did fairly on that part. However, I get your point. Please feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
public class App {

    static class Grade {
        private final String grade;
        private final Integer score;

        public Grade(String grade, Integer score) {
            this.grade = grade;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }

        public Integer getScore() {
            return score;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("score : ");
        int score = sc.nextInt();
        List<Grade> gradeList = new ArrayList<>();
        gradeList.add(new Grade("A", 9));
        gradeList.add(new Grade("B", 8));
        gradeList.add(new Grade("C", 7));
        gradeList.add(new Grade("D", 6));

        Grade s = gradeList.stream()
                .filter(el -> ( score / 10 ) >= el.getScore())
                .findFirst().orElse(new Grade("F", 5));
        System.out.println(s.getGrade());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why easy if complicated is also an option?